# How to quickly determine which process (if any) listens to a serial port

Tags: serial-port, lsof

I am looking for a command to see the process listening to a port, e.g. `/dev/ttyS0` (with root rights on a Linux system). I can do that with

```
lsof /dev/ttyS0
```

but this is really too slow. Also, I cannot use the `-p` flag to make it faster.

I would like to do essentially the same using other resources of the linux system. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've only tried it with a virtual console, but this will work (at least for some resources.  I don't have a Serial port, but it worked for my tty's)

```
fuser -n file /dev/ttyS0
```

(As root, of-course)

Similarly you can look up things speaking to a socket with fuser -n tcp|udp XXXX

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the `-n` option available. But I will look into `fuser`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but for future use.
If lsof (with root rights) is taking too long, the reason can be that it is trying to resolve hostnames when a large number of tcp/udp ports are open. This can be avoided using -n option
`sudo lsof -n /dev/ttyS0`
If -n option is not available then you might try -X option
`sudo lsof -X /dev/ttyS0`